# boot error in kali

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, acpi, firmware

I tried to boot kali using live usb in my laptop (omen 15 ryzen 7 4800h 1650ti). I am having acpi error and firmware error during boot.

I have tried the following and none works:

- All options from grub, including TTY mode
- Downloaded http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-misc-nonfree_20200918-1_all.deb and copying it into the firmware folder and the pool/non-free/f/ folder

My main os is windows 10

Answer (score 1):

In the grub menu, go to the the line of kali linux. Don't press enter, but instead type 'e'. Then you will get a small area to edit the boot command. Then find the line starting with linux, at the end of this command add 'acpi=off'. Then press F10 to boot with this updated command (temporarily). You should boot into the GUI now. This is probably related to the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti graphics card. So you need to install the proprietary nvidia graphics driver. In my case there was also issue with wifi drivers. So i had to manually install the wifi drivers from this repository https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88 . (The instructions are shown there). In your case this maybe a different wifi driver so don't rely on this repository.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
sudo reboot now
```

You may also need to install the proprietary amdgpu drivers (for the integrated Radeon RX Vega 7 GPU ).

Comment: Still not able to boot after that edit i get complete blank screen nothing as an output or something